# Conflict between package pdfcomment and polyglossia under XeLaTeX

Tags: polyglossia, pdfcomment

The following file works fine when run with the choice of "english" but not "portuguese" under XeLaTeX;

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
%  \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  \setdefaultlanguage{portuguese}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

This should show in yellow: \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{Mittag-Leffler}{Highlight} after running \LaTeX{} three times.

\end{document}
```

I am aware of the recommendation by Ulrike Fisher [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517015/conflict-between-package-pdfcomment-and-polyglossia-during-compilation-by-lualat) to load the package `soul` earlier and choose the language later. This solves the problem for LuaLaTeX, but not for XeLaTeX.

Under TL'23, running `xelatex filename`, one gets:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/se-ascii-print.def)
! Extra \else.
\portuguese@sh@tmp ...\portuguese@sh@next --\else 
                                                  \expandafter \portuguese@@...
l.15 ...t,color=yellow]{Mittag-Leffler}{Highlight}
                                                   after running \LaTeX{} th...
```

Are there any ways to run these two packages together under XeLaTeX?

Comment: you are not saying what you mean by "it doesn't work". I have no problems on a current texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this code does NOT run under TL'23. It comes up immediately with an error message, that I have now appended to the question.

Comment: ah sorry, I don't know what I did yesterday. The problem is known https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/660758/2388. Report it to polyglossia, perhaps they find a solution ...

Comment: The problem has been fixed in Polyglossia 1.64.